# Split a string 2 times and put it in a table

Tags: php, html, mysql, split, implode

Ok i have a string which needs to be splitted 2 times.
First time by whitespaces and second time by commas. So i can put it in a table.

I managed to split the string by whitespaces and put it in the first column of the table but i struggle to split it for the second time and put the values in the right column.

Here the snippets of what i already got:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($volumes); $i++) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $volumes[$i] . "</td></tr>";
} ?>
```

Comment: Ok... And you assume we know what your question or problem is? And what `splitStringByWhitespace` is doing? We can guess but it would be nice to know.

Comment: @Andreas my bad.. i rushed it a bit. It is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you render the table rows you should split each volume by comma. I don't understand exactly all the retrieved rows or what is the logic behind your code but this bunch of code should do what you need:

```
<?php 
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($volumes); $i++) {
        echo '<tr>';
        $volumeData = explode(',', $volumes[$i]);
        foreach ($volumeData as $volume) {
            echo '<td>' . $volume . '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the string you provided is accurate? I think there's a coma missing between the size of SystemReserved and the label of the next drive. If that's the case - the code should be something like this:
First we 'explode' the string to create an array, then use array chunk to split it into arrays with seven entries each. And then render it:

```
$string = 'L,Logs,NTFS,Healthy,OK,9.73,9.77 ,SystemReserved,NTFS,Healthy,OK,0.16,0.49 ,C,LocalDisk,NTFS,Healthy,OK,18.19,29.74';
$array = explode(',', $string);
$results = array_chunk($array, 7, true);

?>

<table id="tbl_basic_volumes">
    <tr>
        <th>Buchstabe:</th>
        <th>Name:</th>
        <th>Filesystem:</th>
        <th>Health Status:</th>
        <th>Operational Status:</th>
        <th>Freier Speicherplatz:</th>
        <th>Gesamter Speicherplatz:</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($result as $entry) {
                echo '<td>'.$entry.'</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How i understood array_chunk, i can't use it because of the size parameter. I need it to be dynamic. Matei Mihai's answer is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the inner foreach loop using `implode`.

```
$str = "L,Logs,NTFS,Healthy,OK,9.73,9.77 ,SystemReserved,NTFS,Healthy,OK,0.16,0.49 C,LocalDisk,NTFS,Healthy,OK,18.19,29.74";
$rows = explode(' ', $str);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  echo '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>', explode(',', $row)) . '</td></tr>';
}
```

Or even replacing commas with `</td><td>` will also work:

```
$str = "L,Logs,NTFS,Healthy,OK,9.73,9.77 ,SystemReserved,NTFS,Healthy,OK,0.16,0.49 C,LocalDisk,NTFS,Healthy,OK,18.19,29.74";
$rows = explode(' ', $str);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  echo '<tr><td>' . str_replace(',', '</td><td>', $row) . '</td></tr>';
}
```